# How to convert an array to regular method

Tags: java, arrays, computer-science, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write this code for a class, but I don't want to use an array (`String word[]`). How do I change it so I use a regular method with parentheses?

Also, one of my friends helped and I am trying to learn, and I forgot what the `alright(s);` thing does. I tied to figure it out, but have failed. I think it creates and object for the scan, but I don't really know.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class WordLines{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         String s = scan.nextLine();
        alright(s);
     }
     public static void alright(String s){
         String word[]=s.split(" "); 
         for(int j=0;j<word.length; j++){
             System.out.println(word[j]);
         }
     }
 }
```

Thank you so much for the help!!! :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not 100% sure what you are asking for help with... Could you try to provide us with a little more detail on what your end goal is and what you have attempted so far? To explain the `alright(s);`, it is a method call, it is calling the method defined as `public static void alright(String s) {...` That method splits the String that is passed in as an argument into an array based on spaces then prints each element in the array onto a separate line.

Comment: Oh okay! I understand that part now thank you!!!
Well when my friend helped she told me to do the array and explained it to me, but we haven't learned it in class yet, so I don't want to use it just to be safe. And I am not really sure how to do it without it. For the end product I am trying to get the program to read in a line of text from the keyboard, and then prints to the console the words in the line, each on a separate display line.

Comment: Your program is basically already doing that, there are other ways to accomplish this without using the split command, but not being in your class no one here would be able to tell you what to use. Can you tell us what you have learned about parsing and manipulating Strings? Think about what you would do with the String once you had it stored in the `s` variable, how would you determine what is a "word" and then how would you print that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve similar results without the array is to use an additional instance of the Scanner class to parse the string:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = scan.nextLine();
Scanner parse = new Scanner(s);
while (parse.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(parse.next());
}
```

Link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: This is what I was trying to do! Thank you so much for all the help and for the java api link!!